# Get node inside template if statement

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

On my polymer-based website I created a custom element in that I am loading data via ajax. Depending on the current state of data-loading i created some `<template if="{{}}">` elements to display the right content. It looks something this way:

```
<polymer-element name="modules-item" attributes="moduleID categories">
  <template >
    <service-get-module module="{{module}}" moduleID="{{moduleID}}"></service-get-module>
    <paper-shadow z="1">
        <core-toolbar>
          <span flex  hero-id="title" hero itemprop="name">{{module.title}}</span>
        </core-toolbar>
    </paper-shadow>
    <paper-progress id="moduleLoadingProgress"></paper-progress>
    <template if="{{moduleID == null}}">
        <p>Modul not available</p>
    </template>
    <template if="{{moduleID != null && module == null}}">
        <p>Module is loading...</p>
    </template>
    <template if="{{moduleID != null && module != null}}">
        <div id="moduleContainer">
        <!-- Content //-->
        </div>
   <template>
 </template>
<script>
  Polymer({
    module: null,
    moduleID: null,
    ready: function(){
        console.log(this.$.moduleContainer);
    }
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

That works great, but if I try to access the `<div id="moduleContainer">` I don't get it... I just read so many posts but did not get any solution. May anybode help me? :)

Here is the link to the live website: http://www.test.gruppenstunde.eu/

***UPDATE***

After working a little longer with polymer I found out, that it's easier to use the `hidden?`-Attribute, to casual hide content. Example:

```
<div hidden?="{{moduleID != null}}">Module not available</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access elements within `<template if="{{..}}">` or `<template repeat="{{..}}">` (dynamically created) using the `$` accessor. You need to use `querySelector(...)` and you can the field only when the if expression evaluates to true (the element is actually created/shown)

Comment: Thank you, but with the `querySelector` I don't get the container too. I already thought that in the `ready`-function the variable `module` will be null because that module get it's content after the ajax-progress, so I created the function `moduleChanged` to get the container when the `template` shoud be shown. But that does not work too...

Comment: You could try `domReady` when the expression is initially `true`. If it's `false` you won't be able to get the element because it doesn't exist. In `moduleChanged` you can try to add some delay by using [job](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#job) to allow Polymer to update the view first.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems to be much too difficult for my little purposes. So I will delete all the `if-templates` out of my code and use another way :)

Comment: Often you can add bindings for attributes and events to solve the same thing. When you move the content of the `<template if...>` into a custom element you can use the `attached` or `ready` of this element which is called when `<template if...>` becomes true and adds the content to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

to get access to that element you can put that template in a div and give the div a id.

```
<div id="mod">
  <template if="{{moduleID != null && module != null}}">
    <div id="moduleContainer">
    <!-- Content //-->
    </div>
  <template>
</div>
```

then you can

```
var el = this.$.mod.querySelector("#moduleContainer");
```

Comment: here is a plunker i did of something similar to give you a idea how yo can get this to work. http://plnkr.co/edit/u6shXfgMlUP3UykvLQr7?p=preview maybe don't look for the id and look for the div if it is the only one inside your template.